# Android : Alpha Beta testing

Tags: android

I have updated an apk version 6 in Alpha, I assigned it to a group of tester.

Now I am updating an apk verson 7 in Beta, it says to archive Alpha version 6.

Can't I have two versions in Alpha and Beta at same time?

Sreeram

Answer (score 1):

On a work around, I found -

Alpha version > Beta Version
If these are changing in the hierarchy , the previous versions are archiving.

Sreeram

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but you have to set it up that way. See instructions [in the Google site.](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en)